# Rails, OAuth, and CSRF protection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, oauth, csrf

I am using REST and OAuth to talk to a Rails app (from an iPhone app, but that should not be relevant). However, I am running into some issues with Rails' CSRF protection (via `protects_from_forgery`).

I understand that CSRF protection only kicks in for regular form submissions (i.e. Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded), so I would be fine if I was submitting JSON or XML data. Unfortunately, OAuth is currently limited to application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests. There's a [draft spec that extends OAuth to non-form-urlencoded data](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/spec/ext/body_hash/1.0/drafts/3/spec.html), but this doesn't help me right now.

The way I see it, I have the following options:

1. Send the data as JSON, knowing that it would not be part of the OAuth signature and thus subject to man-in-the-middle attacks. Obviously not an attractive solution.
2. Create special Rails actions (e.g. `UsersController#update_oauth`) that internally delegate to the regular actions (e.g. `UsersController#update`). Then exclude these from the forgery protection (`protects_from_forgery :only => [:update]`). This should work and might be borderline acceptable for one or two actions, but obviously would be a very messy solution.
3. Override the Rails CSRF protection to ignore OAuth requests. I have not tried this, but it seems like it should be possible to change one of the hooks (perhaps the `verify_authenticity_token` filter) to consider OAuth requests successful.

Has anybody run into this before? Any recommendations? Or am I perhaps missing something basic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. :)

I added the following method to our OAuth controller extensions. The only thing this adds on top of the default implementation is the `oauth?` check. This seems to do the trick and feels like a pretty clean solution.

```
def verify_authenticity_token
  verified_request? || oauth? || raise(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)      
end
```